# How to tell when ‘too’ is a conjunction

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

If conjunction joins sentences, how could the word ‘too’ be a conjunction in this sentence:

“Is he coming too?’

Please explain.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/too

Answer (score 1):

The word "too" is an *adverb* in that sentence, not a conjunction.  It means "also" or "additionally"

I can't think of a grammatical English sentence in which "too" is a conjunction.

It can be a linking adverb, relating one sentence to another. This doesn't make it an conjunction.